# Do all member variables of a "new" created instance exist on the heap rather than the stack?

Tags: c++, class, oop, memory-management

The title doesn't really do this one justice...

So, if I create a class (in this case Course, as in golf course) using new - so it's created on the heap, and Course contains a vector of Holes, another class, does the vector have to be a vector of Hole* for them to be on the heap?

```
class course {
    public:
        course(std::string file);

    private:
        std::string name;
        std::vector<hole> holes;
};

class hole {
    public:
        hole(std::string data);

    private:
        std::vector<vec3> vertices;
        std::vector<int> triIndex;
        std::vector<int> boundaryIndex;
};

course currentCourse = new course("datafile.dat");
```

My assumption is that with course being on the heap then all members of course would also be on the heap, but I'm now doubting myself and, yes, this is part of an assignment and I do have to take memory management into account - I've just never come across this scenario before and I'm unsure how to even test whether a variable is in stack or heap memory.

I really hope that I've made this question clear as I'm having trouble phrasing it, and therefore searches aren't much help :( I'm more than happy to post updates if people can point me in the right direction.

Comment: What does this "part of an assignment" actually state, or require, specifically?

Comment: The memory management part of the accompanying report requires "Describe how the memories are managed in your development in this section, to cope with scalability (e.g. 100 players, 20 courses, etc) issues, with detailed diagram and/or code samples (approx 0.5 page)"    
     
I'm aware that dynamic or large datasets should be created on the heap while smaller ones can be left on the stack (and may actually be faster there).

Comment: I see nothing in this "memory management part" that seems to require going into such minutiae. Seems to me that stating that "X is managed by using vectors" will be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Every member of the class will reside on the heap if you allocate memory with `new`. Note that the vector's direct content will only be memory bookkeeping (like its size). The vector will allocate more heap memory for the actual data, regardless of whether the vector resides on the stack or the heap.

Comment: Tangentially related: prefer the term "Dynamic Memory" to "Heap". Heap is an implementation of dynamic memory that is almost universal, but C++ could use pixie dust and hamster wheels if they can be made to meet the requirements. Similarly prefer "Automatic Memory" to "Stack". Usually this doesn't matter, but it could, on an exam for example.

Comment: Thanks guys. I just want to be able to say that since a course could potentially have, say, a million holes, that these are in dynamic memory rather than potentially causing a.. ahem... stack overflow :)

Comment: @sam (sorry if that doesn't tag right on mobile) are you saying that anything stored in a vector is actually stored in dynamic memory, or am I misreading? I've used vectors but never studied them too closely.

Comment: If you use some open source implementation of C++ like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), you could study the implementation source code. And you could also look inside the generated assembler code. For example, see https://godbolt.org/ and on your computer with GCC compile with `g++ -O -fverbose-asm -S` to get the assembler code

Comment: I am saying exactly what I'm saying in my previous comment. Which part of "I see nothing in this memory management part that seems to require going into such minutiae" you are unclear about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does the vector have to be a vector of Hole*

No. `std::vector` is a container that uses dynamic (heap) memory (the same goes for `std::string`). If you had used a container which allocates on the stack, the answer would still be no, since your assumption

> that with course being on the heap then all members of course would also be on the heap

is correct.

In your case, no `new` is needed. You can simply:

```
course myCourse("datafile.dat")
```

A small summary:

```
struct S
{
    void f() { int a = 0; /* local variable a is always on the stack */ }
    int _i = 1; // stack or heap depending on whether the instance of S
                // is on the stack or on the heap
    std::vector<int> _v; // always uses heap (small std::vector's could store their contents
                         // on the stack, but I'll consider that out of scope)
};
```

Note that the member `_v` is on the stack if the instance of `S` is on the stack. However, the content stored in `_v` is on the heap.